# My Rust OR_INSERT Hashmap code to update a struct content works without dereferencing. Why?

Tags: rust, struct, hashmap, dereference

From [Rust documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch08-03-hash-maps.html?highlight=Hashmap%20or_insert#updating-a-hash-map), this **`count`** variable wouldn't work without dereferencing (*)

```
let text = "hello world wonderful world";

let mut map = HashMap::new();

for word in text.split_whitespace() {
    let count = map.entry(word).or_insert(0);
    *count += 1;
}

println!("{:?}", map);
```

However, I have the following code which tries to update a u8 variable (i.e **`team_val.goals_scored`** ) in a Struct if the key is found in a hashmap. It works without dereferencing. My understanding from the above Rust documentation was I need to dereference the `team_val.goals_scored` in order to update the content of the struct which is also a value for the hash map. Whelp!

My code:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Team {
    name: String,
    goals_scored: u8,
    goals_conceded: u8,
}

fn build_scores_table(results: String) -> HashMap<String, Team> {
    // The name of the team is the key and its associated struct is the value.
    let mut scores: HashMap<String, Team> = HashMap::new();

    for r in results.lines() {
        let v: Vec<&str> = r.split(',').collect();
        let team_1_name = v[0].to_string();
        let team_1_score: u8 = v[2].parse().unwrap();
        let team_2_name = v[1].to_string();
        let team_2_score: u8 = v[3].parse().unwrap();

        // TODO: Populate the scores table with details extracted from the
        // current line. Keep in mind that goals scored by team_1
        // will be number of goals conceded from team_2, and similarly
        // goals scored by team_2 will be the number of goals conceded by
        // team_1.

        let mut team_1_struct= Team {
            name: team_1_name.clone(),
            goals_scored: team_1_score,
            goals_conceded: team_2_score
        };

        let mut team_2_struct= Team {
            name: team_2_name.clone(),
            goals_scored: team_2_score,
            goals_conceded: team_1_score
        };

        if scores.contains_key(&team_1_name) {
            let team_val = scores.entry(team_1_name.clone()).or_insert(team_1_struct);
            println!("Yooo {:#?}",team_val);

            team_val.goals_scored +=team_1_score;
            team_val.goals_conceded += team_2_score;
        } else {
            scores.insert(team_1_name,team_1_struct);
        }

        if scores.contains_key(&team_2_name) {
            let team_val = scores.entry(team_2_name.clone()).or_insert(team_2_struct);
            println!("Yooo {:#?}",team_val);

            team_val.goals_scored +=team_2_score;
            team_val.goals_conceded += team_1_score;
        } else {
            scores.insert(team_2_name,team_2_struct);
        }

        
    }
    scores
}
```

Comment: Accessing an object's member via the `.` (dot) operator automatically dereferences the object if possible.

Comment: I love it. I was having existential crisis on what I was missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rust does some automatic dereferencing, [described here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-02-deref.html?highlight=struct%20member%20dereference#implicit-deref-coercions-with-functions-and-methods). We can see the difference between the documentation code and what you wrote:

```
// This
*count += 1
// versus this
team_val.goals_scored += team_1_score
        ^--- Causes an automatic dereferencing
```

If you're coming from C I think [this documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch05-03-method-syntax.html?highlight=struct%20member%20automatic%20dereference#wheres-the---operator) may be even clearer.

Answering the follow-up question 'can you use `entry()` without using `clone()` on the key' - you cannot. `entry()` consumes what you send it, and doesn't give it back, so the borrow checker will prevent you from doing this. It's currently a 'limitation' on the API - but if you're dealing with something as cheap as a short string to copy, then this shouldn't impact you much.

You *can* do a fair amount to slim down your code, though (with the caveat that I only did this for one team - it's easily extensible):

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct Team {
    name: String,
    goals: u8
}

type Scorecard = HashMap<String, Team>;

fn scoring(records: String) -> Scorecard {
    let mut scores : Scorecard = HashMap::new();

    for r in records.lines() {
        let record: Vec<&str> = r.split(',').collect();
        let team_name = record[0].to_string();
        let team_score: u8 = record[1].parse().unwrap();

        // Note that we do not need to create teams here on every iteration. 
        // There is a chance they already exist, and we can create them only if 
        // the `or_insert()` clause is activated.

        // Note that the `entry()` clause when used with `or_insert()`
        // gives you an implicit 'does this key exist?' check.
        let team = scores.entry(team_name.clone()).or_insert(Team {
            name: team_name,
            goals: 0,
        });
        team.goals += team_score;

    }

    scores
}

fn main() {
    let record = "Thunderers,1\nFlashians,1\nThunderers,2";
    let scores = scoring(record.to_string());
    for (key, value) in &scores {
        println!("{}: The mighty {} scored {} points.", key, value.name, value.goals)
    }


    // Flattening Some Options!
    // let o = Some(Some(5));
    // let p = Some(5);
    // println!("o: {:#?}", o);
    // println!("p: {:#?}", p);
    // println!("flattened o: {:#?}", o.flatten());
    // println!("flattened p: {:#?}", p.flatten());
}
```

Comment: Btw is there also a better way of using "team_1_name" instead of cloning it ?

Comment: @WowBow Essentially, no. I updated the answer though.